# Mongoose Indexes for full-text searching

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to find what I got wrong.

If someone can point me to the right direction, that will be great:

My Schema:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
   postID:          String,
   title:           String
});
mongoose.model('post', postSchema, 'posts');
postSchema.index({title: 'text'});
```

Why is this not working:

```
apiRouter.get('/api/searchPosts', function(req, res, next){
    postModel.find(
        { $text : { $search : req.query.text } }
     )
    .exec(function(err, posts) {
        if(posts){
            console.log('The query param is: ' + req.query.text);
            console.log('The posts results is: ' + JSON.stringify(posts));
            res.json({
                posts       :   posts
            });
        } else {
            res.send('Post does not exist');
        }
    });
});
```

The result I get is:

**The query param is: Shayan**

**The posts results is: []**

The post table's title field has "Shayan" in the results so why isn't this working?

Any input will help. Thanks as always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The problem was that I needed to run the below in shell:

```
db.posts.createIndex({"title":"text"})
```

It works perfectly now